# Connecting two devices together with the same ethernet cable (some programming required?)

Tags: ethernet, embedded

I'm looking to connect two devices together via ethernet, but I'm having trouble with the steps needed. The devices are one PC and one microcontroller. Both devices will have static IP's, the microcontroller at the very least. I'm running LWIP on the microcontroller. What I'm stuck with is the steps I need to do to get both devices to communicate. Do I need the microcontroller to do an ARP broadcast or something so both devices can see each other and communicate?

E: Auto-negotiate is enabled on the controller

Comment: in the old days you needed to use cross-patch cable to connect directly between two computers. cross-patch reroutes the send pins to the recieve pins on the other side. then a technology called MDI-X became common, and it would detect and set your pin mapping dynamically for whatever cable you had. if your nics or driver do not support MDI-X, try re-cabling with cross-patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, but I used an 8-bit PIC with an integrated ethernet controller.
I'm a bit unclear on which step you're having problems with, setting up LWIP or the hardware configuration or both.

You should be able to just use standard TCP sockets on both ends, but you'll either need to plug both devices into a hub or switch, or you'll have to use a crossover ethernet cable if you want to connect the two devices directly. Modern ethernet controllers might have the crossover ability built in. You'll have to check the manual for your computer's NIC and the ethernet controller on the MCU. Basic, older, ethernet has a transmit pair of wires and a receive pair. So you can't connect two controllers directly with a straight cable or else you'll be connecting a transmit pair to another transmit pair instead of a receive pair. But check with your controllers, this might be taken care of (and you can turn a regular ethernet cable into a crossover one yourself, it's  easy to do).

I haven't used LWIP, I used Microchip's proprietary stack, but I imagine they're somewhat similar. I would recommend making sure to enable ping on the MCU, so you can easily use ping to see if you have proper connectivity. Microchip's stack required you to continually call a function that handles the processing for the network stack. I imagine LWIP has something similar, where you'll have to have a task, a thread, or some sort of co-operative multitasking setup on the mcu that calls LWIP's processing function. So you can't just repeatedly call send on the socket, you must call the stack processing function, which is when the bytes will actually get sent.

Comment: Works in this configuration, I had an internal watchdog enabled accidentally and it was causing the controller to produce nothing. Runs LWIP setup with ICMP enabled, sets static IP. Works great. Auto-negotiation on LWIP does the crossover work.